# Mail.app not showing new IMAP mailbox

Tags: mail.app, ventura, imap

In Mail.app Version 16.0 (3731.700.6): I created a new subfolder in an IMAP account by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on the parent, choosing "New Mailbox...", and entering the name.  The new mailbox does not appear in the tree, but trying to create it again gets the error that the mailbox already exists.

**How can I get Mail to show the new mailbox(/subfolder) that does exist but is not shown?**